# Django: Print url of view without hardcoding the url

Tags: python, django

Can i print out a url `/admin/manage/products/add` of a certain view in a template?

Here is the rule i want to create a link for

```
(r'^manage/products/add/$', create_object, {'model': Product, 'post_save_redirect': ''}),
```

I would like to have /manage/products/add in a template without hardcoding it. How can i do this?

**Edit:** I am not using the default admin (well, i am but it is at another url), this is my own

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use `get_absolute_url`, but that will only work for a particular object.  Since your object hasn't been created yet, it won't work in this case.

You want to use [named URL patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns).  Here's a quick intro:

Change the line in your urls.py to:

```
(r'^manage/products/add/$', create_object, {'model': Product, 'post_save_redirect': ''}, "create-product"),
```

Then, in your template you use this to display the URL:

```
{% url create-product %}
```

If you're using Django 1.5 or higher you need this:

```
{% url 'create-product' %}
```

You can do some more powerful things with named URL patterns, they're very handy.  Note that they are only in the development version (and also 1.0).

Comment: How can I call url in my view?  E.g., return HttpResponseRedirect(...) where ... is the value of url create-product

Comment: Don't forget to add `name=` in the `urls.py`, like so: `(r'^view/$', 'view.function', name='hiya')`

Answer (score 2):

If you use [named url patterns](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/topics/http/urls/#naming-url-patterns) you can do the follwing in your template

```
{% url create_object %}
```

Answer (score 0):

The preferred way of creating the URL is by adding a `get_absolute_url` method to your model classes. You can hardcode the path there so you at least get closer to following the KISS philosophy.

You can go further by utilizing the `permalink` decorator that figures the path based on the urls configuration.

You can read more in the django documentation [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url).